# Assistance with Internet Explorer bug, overflow in right column in a 3-column design layout

Tags: css, internet-explorer, layout

I would need some help with a Internet Explorer bugs in my 3-column layout design.

The problem arises when I am using IE 8. With Firefox 3.6 and Chrome (Latest) the layout behaves as supposed. But in IE the right (pink) column flows to the right and I also get an unwanted x-scrollbar. It's supposed to be aligned with the header and the footer.

I believe it's a easy task to solve for the web programmers dealing with cross compatible sites before.

The page is super simple, only to point out the layout.

[Link to the page](http://www.student.bth.se/~tisc10/layout/)

Thank you!

EDIT: One of the original question is fixed with the help from the first answer. The footer was overflowing to the left and was fixed with a style attribute "zoom:1;".
Thank you **Genius**!

Comment: What kind of help? On StackOverflow you should ask a specific question that can have a testable answer. We can't help without a direct inquiry as to what is wrong and what you want help with.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Note that "it's broken" is not meaningful enough description, and neither is "you'll know it when you see it" (not all of us are using IE by default). Please edit your question, and add relevant data - such as what did you expect the page to look like, how it differs in reality (in what browsers? IE versions are currently spread from 6 to 9, which ones? What OS?), and what you already tried. If you create the smallest version of the page that still contains this bug, you may get even more useful answers.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I've fixed my question as much as I could think of. Only screen-shots are left out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add a style "zoom: 1" to your footer:

```
<div class="footer" style="zoom: 1;">
```

and keep in mind that for better compatibility you should specify the DOCTYPE header for your page

Comment: Thank you!
I've added a doctype and the zoom attribute. Now I only need help to put the right column into place.